# Installing Windows 10, no option of “remove the installation medium and reboot”

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb

After reading several threads with no help or real answer I try to post this question.

I am having an Ubuntu Laptop. I would like to install Windows on it. When I boot from USB I do end up in an installation loop, as described in many forum threads. That means PC is starting from USB and then after installation restarts and again boots from USB. 
Microsoft  does not provide any feasible instruction on this. Often suggested is the boot priority HDD, USB, CD, which clearly works on new HDD but is not really helpful in my case.

One can argue that starting in a “chose boot device” mode could help. I do not have this option on my PC.

I fully understand that I can remove USB stick from the PC during the new start, hoping that during the new start a right moment is chosen to remove the USB device “safely”. This seems to me not the way of installation Microsoft has plant.

So my question is: how to do it PROPERLY in the right manner.

Comment: After you install Windows, enter the firmware settings, eject the disk at that point.  You can also eject it while at the first step of the installation process, at that point all the files have been copied into memory, and being accessed from the flash drive

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the USB. It really doesn't matter, just pull it out after you click "restart" or when the timer runs out on the restart countdown.